# How to prove the inequality $|e^z-1| \geq |z|/2$ for sufficiently small $|z|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to prove the inequality $|e^z-1| \geq |z|/2$ for sufficiently small $|z|$?
I was thinking about the Taylor series for $e^z$, but I have no idea.
Any answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $g(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}$, defined as $1$ at the origin, is a holomorphic function in the disk $|z|<2\pi$. It follows that $|g(z)|\leq 2$ in a wide neighbourhood of the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By L'Hopital's Rule $\frac {e^{z}-1} z \to 1$ as $z \to 0$. Hence $|\frac {e^{z}-1} z|\geq \frac  1 2$ for $|z|$ sufficiently small.

Proof using power series: $e^{z}-1=z+\frac {z^{2}} {2!}+...$ so $|e^{z}-1| \geq |z|-|z|(\frac {|z|} {2!}+\frac {|z|^{2}} {3!}+...)$. Use the fact that $|\frac {|z|} {2!}+\frac {|z|^{2}} {3!}+...|\leq |z| e$ for $|z| <1$ Can you complete the proof now?

Comment: Does L'Hopital's rule hold for complex functions?

Comment: It does. I will also add another proof in a minute.

Comment: You don't need L'Hôpital's rule here. $\frac {e^{z}-1} z$ converges to the *derivative* of $e^z$ at $z=0$.

Comment: @MartinR You are right. Thanks for the comment.